# using fopen_s and customise file name in c

Tags: c

I know that if I want to use `fopen_s`, it should be in this format `fopen_s(*file,"name.txt","w")`.

But if I want to customise the file name, what should I do?
I have tried `fopen_s(*file,str,"w")` where `str` is  `"file.txt"`, but it just showed HELP and didn't create any file. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
char str[100];
    printf("Enter .txt file name\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    FILE *fp;

    fopen_s(&fp, str, "w");
if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("HELP\n");    exit(1);
    }
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: It might not work because you don't pass the first argument correctly? Perhaps if you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, and tell us what problems you have( ***how*** "it does not work") we could help you better. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code after your edit make more sense. And should work. Or rather, it should work if you could open the file, which you can't. And that's what `fp == NULL` mean, that `fopen_s` could not open the file (which you really should know if you tried to read any kind of documentation!). Do the file you enter as input exist? Do all parts of the path exist? What happens if you give an *absolute* path as input instead?

Comment: If I use fopen_s(&fp,"filename.txt","w"), it works and creates a txt file named "filename" instead of showing HELP. But what I want is customising the file name in the program. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: That's because str actually contains "filename.txt\n" and not "filename.txt". And presumably you are running this on Windows where newlines are not allowed in filenames, hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

Read what `fgets` does:
`fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.`

You need to print what you get to ensure what you passed is a valid filename(for example there shouldn't be an `\n`)

A good way to solve these issues is to start small by for example by assigning something to `str` to ensure the rest of the code works and then move on and try to include reading from `STDIN`.

Another useful thing is to check `errno` that was returned by `fopen_s` which will give you a good idea what happened.